# Django manage request to an static file url

Tags: django

Does django have any method to process some logic before return static file?

*Example:*
request to http://example.com/some-file.js would be passed through an logic function before return that javascript file?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to put a `signal` on an `AppConfig`? Then you can create a custom `AppConfig` for the `staticfiles` app and adjust it there.

Comment: Django is not supposed to serve static files on prod. So it will never know that someone requested this file.